# СИ | Ошибка Вызвано исключение по адресу 0x78EAEE39 (ucrtbased.dll) в lab6.2.exe: 0xC0000005: нарушение прав доступа при записи по адресу 0xCCCCCCCC

Tags: c

```
    #include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <locale.h>

char mindl(char *s2) {
    char *s3[1000];
    int i = 0;
    char* p;
    p = strtok(s2, " ");
    while (p != NULL)
    {
        printf("%s\n", p);
        p = strtok(s2, " ");
        while (p != NULL) {
            strcpy(s3[i], p);
            i++;
            p = strtok(NULL, " ");
        }
    }
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    char s1[1000];
    char rez[1000];
    int n;
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
    printf("Введите количетсво строк: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    while (getchar() != '\n');
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        printf("Введите строку: ");
        gets(s1);
        mindl(s1);

    }
  }
```

Не работает код, жалуется на strcpy(s3[i], p); Ошибка Вызвано исключение по адресу 0x78EAEE39 (ucrtbased.dll) в lab6.2.exe: 0xC0000005: нарушение прав доступа при записи по адресу 0xCCCCCCCC.

Comment: Куда указывают указатели в массиве `s3`?

Comment: Никуда, просто пробовал добавлять/убирать указать в массиве s3. Потому что программа отказывалась работать

Comment: Если указатели указывают в никуда, то что делает эта строка: `strcpy(s3[i], p);`?

Comment: Копирует p в s3[i]. Т.е по идее копирует слово в массив.

Comment: Указатель `s3[i]` должен указывать на какую-то память, чтобы `strcpy` смогла туда скопировать что-то.

Comment: И как это исправить?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`strcpy(s3[i], p);` копирует содержимое строки `p` в область памяти, на которую указывает `s[i]`. Вам нужно обеспечить, чтобы по этому адресу было достаточно памяти, чтобы вместить содержимое `p`.

Самый простой вариант

```
            size_t len = strlen(p);
            s[i] = malloc(len+1);
            if (s[i] == NULL) { perror("Out of memory"); exit(-1); }
            strcpy(s3[i], p);
```

Пожалуйста, учитесь сразу делать хорошо. Даже в учебных заданиях.

Вы не проверили возвращаемое значение `scanf`. Что будет, если клиент введёт что-нибудь вроде `qwerty` вместо числа?
Вы не проверили число `n`, вдруг оно отрицательное или, наоборот, сильно большое?

Функция `main` должна возвращать целое число, но вы ничего не возвращаете.

Вы пользуетесь функцией `gets` для чтения строки. Это категорически небезопасная функция, прямая дорога к атаке через переполнение буфера. Для безопасного чтения строк уже давно придумана функция [`getline`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getline.3.html)

Объявив `char *s3[1000];` вы ожидаете, что будет не более тысячи слов в строке. А если будет тысяча и одна? Привет, переполнение буфера на стеке.

Это можно назвать мелкими придирками, но из такой небрежности впоследствии могут вырасти ошибки совсем другого масштаба, чем проблемы с доступом к памяти в учебной задаче.

Comment: "Объявив char *s3[1000]; вы ожидаете, что будет не более тысячи слов в строке. А если будет тысяча и одна? Привет, переполнение буфера на стеке."
Я работаю в вижуалке, которая отказывается создавать переменные переменной длинны, требует константное значение.

Comment: @Vladislav, есть минимум три пути. 1) Остановить обработку, если достигнут предел слов в строке. 2) Выделить память для `s3` вызовом `calloc`. Если предел достигнут, сделать `realloc`. 3) использовать динамическую структуру, такую как односвязный список. Есть и "план Б" - перейти на C++ и `std::vector`. Вариантов, как видите, масса. Только ни в коем случае не работать с массивом без ограничений.